Proving that an algebraic (aborescent) link that has exactly one negative sign in its Conway notation has an almost alternating projection
I'm working on Exercise 5.32 in The Knot Book by Colin Adams, which asks to prove that an algebraic link that has exactly one negative sign in its Conway notation has an almost alternating projection.
In Adams et al.'s paper, they provide a proof for this (in the proof for Theorem 3.1), but I'm confused by the reasoning.

They say, "Using Conway’s rules we can move a negative sign
through the notation to the end of a parenthetical or to a period." What rules allow for this? I'm using just The Knot Book right now, and it doesn't seem to answer this.

"If the last integer in the string after this process is a, changing the a- to a+ will change exactly one
crossing in the projection." Doesn't a- correspond to |a| left-handed crossings/crossings with a negative slope? Why wouldn't changing the a- to a+ require changing |a| crossings?


Would appreciate any help! Thanks
